# Binary operation in C

Tags: c, binary, char

I have two characters

```
char c1='A', c2 = 'B';
```

since 8-bit binary of `A` is `01000001` and binary of `B` is `01000010`. I want the left-most bit of `B` to be put into the right-Most bit of `A` so that c1 becomes `01000000`. I am doing this by calculating binaries A and B and then geting new binary and then doing described process and then assigning the new binary to `c1`.
My question is whether there is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Note that `'A'` and `'a'` are not the same thing.  Other than that, combining various bit-wise operations will do this efficiently. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leftmost bit of `c2` is:

```
c2 & 0x80
```

To move this into the rightmost bit, you use a right-shift:

```
(c2 & 0x80) >> 7
```

To combine this with `c1`, you first have to clear out the rightmost bit of `c1`:

```
(c1 & 0xfe)
```

Then you combine them with `|`:

```
c1 = (c1 & 0xfe) | ((c2 & 0x80) >> 7);
```

You should also change your declarations to `unsigned char` to avoid problems with the sign bit. It's generally best to use only `unsigned` variables when using bitwise operations.

Comment: Will `((c2 & 0x80) >> 7)` get sign extended since c2 is a signed char? How about `((c2  >> 7) & 0x1)`?

Comment: @JS1 I've changed my answer to recommend using unsigned.

Comment: @JS1: Note that while I think using `unsigned` types in bit operations is a good idea, neither of those expressions will be bothered by sign extension since the `&` operations will get rid of any sign extended bits.  Even in `((c2 & 0x80) >> 7)` there will be no sign bit to extend in the shift operation because the result of `(c2 & 0x80)` is an `int` (not a `char` or `signed char`) that won't have any sign bits set.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Good point, you're right. I've just been burned so many times by sign extension bugs that now I just instinctively distrust right shifting of anything signed.

Comment: @MichaelBurr AndrewLui's answer suffers from that problem because he didn't mask before shifting.

Comment: @Barmar: yes - I was just pointing out a more or less pedantic detail.  I generally agree that using unsigned types for bit twiddling is a good idea.

Comment: @barmar i dont want to destroy the contents of c2 too.

Comment: I don't have any assignment to `c2`, it doesn't get modified.

Answer (score -1):

you want this:

```
c1 = (c1 & 0xfe) | (c2 >> 7);
```

Comment: Don't you need to do a right-shift to move the leftmost bit into the rightmost bit?

Comment: oops, I missed the right-most to left-most part, fixed it. thanks.